# How can I perform set operations on Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

While it is incredibly useful to be able to do set operations between the keys of a dictionary, I often wish that I could perform the set operations on the dictionaries themselves.

I found some recipes for taking [the difference of two dictionaries](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576644-diff-two-dictionaries/) but I found those to be quite verbose and felt there must be more pythonic answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tl;dr Recipe: `{k:d1.get(k, k in d1 or d2[k]) for k in set(d1) | set(d2)}` and `|` can be replaced with any other set operator.

Based @torek's comment, another recipe that might be easier to remember (while being fully general) is: `{k:d1.get(k,d2.get(k)) for k in set(d1) | set(d2)}`.

Full answer below:

My first answer didn't deal correctly with values that evaluated to False. Here's an improved version which deals with Falsey values:

```
>>> d1 = {'one':1, 'both':3, 'falsey_one':False, 'falsey_both':None}
>>> d2 = {'two':2, 'both':30, 'falsey_two':None, 'falsey_both':False}
>>> 
>>> print "d1 - d2:", {k:d1[k] for k in d1 if k not in d2}                  # 0
d1 - d2: {'falsey_one': False, 'one': 1}
>>> print "d2 - d1:", {k:d2[k] for k in d2 if k not in d1}                  # 1
d2 - d1: {'falsey_two': None, 'two': 2}
>>> print "intersection:", {k:d1[k] for k in d1 if k in d2}                      # 2
intersection: {'both': 3, 'falsey_both': None}
>>> print "union:", {k:d1.get(k, k in d1 or d2[k]) for k in set(d1) | set(d2)}   # 3
union: {'falsey_one': False, 'falsey_both': None, 'both': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1, 'falsey_two': None}
```

The version for `union` is the most general and can be turned into a function:

```
>>> def dict_ops(d1, d2, setop):
...     """Apply set operation `setop` to dictionaries d1 and d2
... 
...     Note: In cases where values are present in both d1 and d2, the value from
...     d1 will be used.
...     """
...     return {k:d1.get(k,k in d1 or d2[k]) for k in setop(set(d1), set(d2))}
... 
>>> print "d1 - d2:", dict_ops(d1, d2, lambda x,y: x-y)
d1 - d2: {'falsey_one': False, 'one': 1}
>>> print "d2 - d1:", dict_ops(d1, d2, lambda x,y: y-x)
d2 - d1: {'falsey_two': None, 'two': 2}
>>> import operator as op
>>> print "intersection:", dict_ops(d1, d2, op.and_)
intersection: {'both': 3, 'falsey_both': None}
>>> print "union:", dict_ops(d1, d2, op.or_)
union: {'falsey_one': False, 'falsey_both': None, 'both': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1, 'falsey_two': None}
```

Where items are in both dictionaries, the value from `d1` will be used. Of course we can return the value from `d2` instead by changing the order of the function arguments.

```
>>> print "union:", dict_ops(d2, d1, op.or_)
union: {'both': 30, 'falsey_two': None, 'falsey_one': False, 'two': 2, 'one': 1, 'falsey_both': False}
```

Comment: Heh, `k in d1 or d2[k]` as a default value if `k` isn't in `d1` is pretty cool: it avoids evaluating `d2[k]` exactly whenever `k` is in `d1` so that the second argument to `d1.get` is not needed :-)  (Note that `d2.get(k)` would also work but requires looking in `d2`; not sure if that's really any less efficient in the end.)

Comment: @torek Thanks. Based on what you said the following also works and might be the easiest to remember: `{k:d1.get(k,d2.get(k)) for k in set(d1) | set(d2)}` .

Comment: @snth great answer! One question: How does this part work ````setop(set(d1), set(d2)```` when your function input is ````op.or_```` or ````lambda x,y: x-y````?

Comment: @gython Those operators are defined for sets so they just work. I think look up the relevant documentation for sets if you want more details.

Comment: @snth thanks that helped! One last question: About this part ``(k,k in d1 or d2[k])``? Why do you need the single ``k`` and whats the difference between ``k in d1`` and ``d1[k]`` regarding the functionality? Thanks!

Comment: What you really want is `d1.get(k,d2[k])` but the problem is that if `k` is in `d1` but not in `d2` then you get an `IndexError` or `LookupError` as the function parameters are evaluated before the function is called. So the `k in d1` part is there to guard against that because the short circuit `or` operator will prevent the second expression being evaluated in the case where `k` is in `d1`.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: The recipes here don't deal correctly with False values. I've submitted another improved answer.

Here are some recipes I've come up with:

```
>>> d1 = {'one':1, 'both':3}
>>> d2 = {'two':2, 'both':30}
>>> 
>>> print "d1 only:", {k:d1.get(k) or d2[k] for k in set(d1) - set(d2)}     # 0
d1 only: {'one': 1}
>>> print "d2 only:", {k:d1.get(k) or d2[k] for k in set(d2) - set(d1)}     # 1
d2 only: {'two': 2}
>>> print "in both:", {k:d1.get(k) or d2[k] for k in set(d1) & set(d2)}     # 2
in both: {'both': 3}
>>> print "in either:", {k:d1.get(k) or d2[k] for k in set(d1) | set(d2)}   # 3
in either: {'both': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

While the expressions in #0 and #2 could be made simpler, I like the generality of this expression which allows me to copy and paste this recipe everywhere and simply change the set operation at the end to what I require.

Of course we can turn this into a function:

```
>>> def dict_ops(d1, d2, setop):
...     return {k:d1.get(k) or d2[k] for k in setop(set(d1), set(d2))}
... 
>>> print "d1 only:", dict_ops(d1, d2, lambda x,y: x-y)
d1 only: {'one': 1}
>>> print "d2 only:", dict_ops(d1, d2, lambda x,y: y-x)
d2 only: {'two': 2}
>>> import operator as op
>>> print "in both:", dict_ops(d1, d2, op.and_)
in both: {'both': 3}
>>> print "in either:", dict_ops(d1, d2, op.or_)
in either: {'both': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
>>> print "in either:", dict_ops(d2, d1, lambda x,y: x|y)
in either: {'both': 30, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Comment: Watch out for cases where `d1[k]` exists but `bool(d1[k])` is `False`, e.g., if `d1['both'] = 0` you get `d2['both']`.  This seems entirely valid—if it's in both dictionaries, which value is the "right" one?—but if you're expecting to get the value from `d1` and you *usually* get the values from d1, this could be a surprise.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you labeled the operations the same as the equivalent set operation -- like union, intersection, difference, etc.

Comment: @torek You're right about the False values. I've submitted a new answer that hopefully deals with these correctly. I didn't edit this answer because I think the new answer is too different and people had already voted on it.

Comment: @martineau Thanks, I've relabeled the output in my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I'd like to highlight my `ubelt` package (https://github.com/Erotemic/ubelt), which contains a solutions to this problem.

I'm not sure why PEP584 only added union and no other set operations to dictionaries. I'll need to look into it more to see if there is any existing rational for why Python dictionaries do not contain these methods by default (I imagine there must be, I don't see how the devs could not be aware of set operations on dictionaries).

But to the point. Ubelt implements these functions for core dictionary set operations:

- [ubelt.dict_diff](https://ubelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ubelt.util_dict.html#ubelt.util_dict.dict_diff) - analog of set.difference
- [ubelt.dict_union](https://ubelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ubelt.util_dict.html#ubelt.util_dict.dict_union) - analog of set.union
- [ubelt.dict_isect](https://ubelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ubelt.util_dict.html#ubelt.util_dict.dict_isect) - analog of set.intersection

I hope someday these or something similar are added to Python dictionaries themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [funcy](https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
>>> import funcy
>>> a = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> b = {3: 5, 6: 8}
>>> funcy.merge(a, b)
{1: 2, 3: 5, 6: 8}
>>> funcy.project(a, b)
{3: 4}
>>> funcy.omit(a, b)
{1: 2}
>>> a, b
({1: 2, 3: 4}, {3: 5, 6: 8})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some more:

Set addition `d1 + d2`

```
{key: value for key, value in d1.items() + d2.items()}
# here values that are present in `d1` are replaced by values in `d2`
```

Alternatively,

```
d3 = d1.copy()
d3.update(d2)
```

Set difference `d1 - d2`

```
{key: value for key, value in d1.items() if key not in d2}
```

Comment: And your set difference is set intersection.