# How can I use lambda as function parameter?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

The author of the top answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694261/how-can-i-perform-set-operations-on-python-dictionaries) question uses a lamda function as parameter for this function:

```
>>> d1 = {'one':1, 'both':3, 'falsey_one':False, 'falsey_both':None}
>>> d2 = {'two':2, 'both':30, 'falsey_two':None, 'falsey_both':False}


def dict_ops(d1, d2, setop):
...     """Apply set operation `setop` to dictionaries d1 and d2
... 
...     Note: In cases where values are present in both d1 and d2, the value from
...     d1 will be used.
...     """
...     return {k:d1.get(k,k in d1 or d2[k]) for k in setop(set(d1), set(d2))}
```

Like this:

```
>>> print "d1 - d2:", dict_ops(d1, d2, lambda x,y: x-y)
```

Which returns:

```
d1 - d2: {'falsey_one': False, 'one': 1}
```

I tried to do the same thing but not as a function, because I want to understand how the `setop` part works.

```
{k:d1.get(k,k in d1 or d2[k]) for k in lambda d1,d2: set(d1) - set(d2)}
```

However this code returns a syntax error.

But this works:

```
l = lambda d1,d2: set(d1) - set(d2)
{k:d1.get(k,k in d1 or d2[k]) for k in l(d1,d2)}
```

Why does the second solution work, but the first one dont?

If I call the dict_ops function with these parameters `(d1, d2, lambda x,y: x-y)` how does `setop(set(d1) - set(d2)` look like?

Comment: You're not *calling* the `lambda`. `(lambda d1,d2: set(d1) - set(d2))(d1, d2)` would work.

Comment: So I need to provide the ````lambda```` *function* with paramters? Was my mistake that I just 'wrote' a ````lambda```` *function* without providing parameters?

Comment: That's part of it. It would be syntactically valid if you just surrounded it with parentheses, but you'd get a TypeError ('function' object is not iterable) instead. You can define a lambda function *without* calling it, that's just not what you actually want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an exact substitution, it will work.  You have:

```
{... for k in setop(set(d1), set(d2))}
```

The value passed in for `setop` is:

```
lambda x,y: x-y
```

A direct substitution of `setop` is:

```
{... for k in (lambda x,y: x-y)(set(d1), set(d2))|
```

which will work.

For the second version, you have:

```
{... for k in l(d1,d2)}
```

where `l` is:

```
lambda d1,d2: set(d1) - set(d2)
```

A direct substitution here produces:

```
{... for k in (lambda d1,d2: set(d1) - set(d2))(d1,d2)}
```

which will also work.